# Trouble with ESP32 timer Arduino

Tags: timer, arduino, esp32

I have a trouble with esp32.
I want a 128Hz (7812.5µs) timer from the 240MHz esp32 clock.
I set the prescaler to 120 and 15625 ticks to get the desired frequency.

240Mhz / 120 = 2Mhz
2MHz / 15625 = 128Hz

But when I run the following code, the serial monitor prints "3000" every 3s whereas it should be "1000" every seconds.

```
#define TMR_ID 0
#define TMR_PRESCALER 120

unsigned long start_ = 0;

float counter = 0;

hw_timer_t *timer = NULL;
void IRAM_ATTR timer_isr(void) {
  counter++;
}

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  timer = timerBegin(TMR_ID, TMR_PRESCALER, true);                  //timer 0, div 120
  timerAttachInterrupt(timer, &timer_isr, true);  //attach callback
  timerAlarmWrite(timer, 15625, true); //set time in us
  timerAlarmEnable(timer);
  Serial.print("start");
  start_ = millis();
}

void loop() {
  if (counter == 128) {
    Serial.println(millis() - start_);
    counter = 0;
    start_ = millis();
  }

}
```

By replacing the prescaler by 40, it seems to work normaly.
Does someone as an answer to this please ?

Answer (score 0):

Usually the timer clock is set to 80 MHz, even when the CPU clock is set to 240 MHz.
So replacing the prescaler by 40 will solve the equation.
(80Mhz/40)/15625 = 128Hz